# Use Of Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Even though It has a performance issue, may I know what is the use of correlated subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, firstly it doesn't have a performance issue. It is what it is, and it will be executed as well as possible given the performance constraints of the hardware and database structure.

As for what it is useful for, it is just a way of expressing particular logical conditions.

Comment: Why it wont be having performance issue as it firstly finds record in outer query then pass it to inner query and then inner query will will give some result depending upon which again outer query selects expected result....

Comment: @hrishi: Because that's not what it does. SQL is declarative, so you write your desired results, not the operations to get to that result. Determining how to retrieve your result is a job for the query optimizer.

Comment: What you're describing there is pretty much a join. The query transformation stage of the optimisation process can convert a correlated subquery to a join and it could be implemented as a hash join or nested loop (etc). A correlated subquery against a very large unindexed table could well be a performance issue but that's because the join is inefficient, not because the syntax for specifying it in SQL implies an inherently ineffcient database operation.

Answer (score 8):

One common usage example: display details of the latest hired employee(s) for each department:

```
select e.deptno, e.empno, e.ename, e.hiredate, e.sal
from   emp e
where  e.hiredate = (select max(e2.hiredate)
                     from   emp e2
                     where  e2.deptno = e.deptno -- the correlation
                    );
```

Comment: This is the most clear use that I have seen in SO about uses of correlated subqueries.

Comment: Can you think of any special case where correlated subquery is indispensable? I guess the above result can be achieved with "select * from emp group by deptno 
 having hiredate = MAX(hiredate)" .

Comment: @bluelurker That wouldn't work in Oracle (I don't know about some other DBMSs) as you cannot select all columns and then only group by deptno.

Comment: Ok, I tried that in Sybase ASE and it works fine. Glad you pointed that out.

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery is used some action must be taken on each row in your query that depends on one or more values from that row.

So, for instance, if you want to know include a row in a result set based on something happening in another table, you might do:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable YT WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable SOT WHERE
    SOT.ID = YT.ID AND SOT.SomeInteger BETWEEN YT.LowInteger AND YT.HighInteger)
```

Similarly in an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE YourTable YT SET YourColumn = 
  (SELECT SUM(SomeColumn) FROM SomeOtherTable SOT 
      WHERE SOT.ID = YT.ID AND SOT.SomeField <> YT.SomeField)
```

Sometimes these queries can be written with standard JOINs, but sometimes not.